# How to implement Add and Remove griditem functionality in angular2-grid?

Tags: angular

I have to implement Add and remove box functionlity using Angular2 grid  and below is my sample box using Angular2-grid.

On Click of button X in header handle, I want to remove current grid item. Please suggest how to achieve Add and Remove grid item functionality?

```
<div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{\'max_cols\': 10,\'max_rows\': 10, \'auto_resize\': true}">
    <div [ngGridItem]="{'dragHandle': '.handle', 'fixed': true, 'col': 1, 'row': 1}">
        <div class="handle">Header <button type="button" (click)="selectClose()">X</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ngIf against the grid element and bind it to a boolean property in the component like so. Switch the boolean value on click of X.

```html
<div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{\'max_cols\': 10,\'max_rows\': 10, \'auto_resize\': true}">
    <div [ngGridItem]="{'dragHandle': '.handle', 'fixed': true, 'col': 1, 'row': 1}" *ngIf="showItem">
        <div class="handle">Header <button type="button" (click)="showItem = !showItem">X</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the component class

```js
@Component ({
  ...
  })

export class SomeComponent {
  showItem: boolean = true;

  }
```